# How to fix AlertDialog not wrapping to layout on all devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I tried setting my `alertDialog` theme to `R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents_Light_Dialog_Alert`

While that worked to wrap the content of my `alertDialog` to my layout inflated on my huawei y9 (android pie) but it did not wrap the content on a lenovo api 19

I tried setting `LayoutParams` to `wrap_content` but still it did nothing:

```
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx)
    val viewInflater = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_menu,null)
    val window = AlertDialog.Builder(mCtx,R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents_Light_Dialog_Alert)
            .setView(viewInflater)
            .setCancelable(false)
    alertD = window.create()
    //alertD.window?.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    alertD.show()
```

So I need my `AlertDialog` to wrap its content to my layout on all phones.

Comment: in your R.layout.popup_menu set parent continer w/h to wrap_content

Comment: Its already set to wrap_content but the alertDialog is the problem

Answer (score 2):

try creating custom Dialog Style and add Width and height in percentage.

**min_Width_minor is:**

> The platform's desired minimum size for a dialog's width when it is
>   along the minor axis (that is the screen is portrait). This may be
>   either a fraction or a dimension.

**Min_witdh_major is:**

> The platform's desired minimum size for a dialog's width when it is
>   along the minor axis (that is the screen is portrait). This may be
>   either a fraction or a dimension.

try below Example.

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">

    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">80%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">80%</item>
    <item name="windowFixedHeightMinor">80%</item>
    <item name="windowFixedHeightMajor">80%</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">#FFC107</item>
    <!-- Used for the title and text -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <!-- Used for the background -->
    <item name="android:background">#4CAF50</item>

</style>


 AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
        myAlert.setTitle("Title");
        myAlert.setMessage("1298201");
        myAlert.show();
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is a good idea because i am using a layout inflated as the view of my dialog

Comment: try this approach these is nothing wrong with it.  does not matter if you are using custom layout or not.

Comment: I just tried it but changed width to 10% for it to wrap content while it worked on my huawei(android 9 pie) device like it was before. It did not work on my lenovo device lenovo (api 19) it did not get affected by it even for 50% it stayed the same.

Comment: try using Simple Dialog or DialogFragment if it does not help you

Comment: I have already changed from popupwindow to alertdialog because it also had some issues of not showing up in popupwindow this is getting way too annoying 2 days stuck on same issue no solution